# Bool wrong evaluated in If statement

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, if-statement, boolean

Just for curiosity

I have this problem on my code.

[image]

`e` is evaluated as `false`, (and I know that is getting false by seeing the data in the db) but the if statement doesn't care that, and assumes that is true, and is trying to throwing the exception.

Any ideas why?

**edit:**

- There is no ; at the end of line 16.
- The value `false` is correct, I have checked the database and is
  correct that is getting `false`, that was the expected
- the thing not expected is to get the exception
- Yes, with `{}` works fine. BUT I WANT TO KNOW why in this way is not
  working.
- Yes, clean, build, rebuild, everything, and getting the same
- No, I don't change the code while debugging. My solution is under `x64`, I'm not able to do the change

Comment: Try `if (fracciones.Any(q => !q.FechaSegundoScan.HasValue))` and see if that fails.

Comment: So if you hover of 'e' its false ?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance yup, that failed too. AS you can see before the if statement, I tried several times with different variables the same query (even putting directly on if statement [that was I did in first place]) and same.. not working

Comment: I don't believe that all of your assertions are correct.

Comment: I press "end" key on if line, and I'm not getting the cursor move. If I use {} it works fine, but I want to know why this is happening

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Is the exception *actually* thrown or does the debugger just appear to step to the line? It is a *critical failure* if the exception is thrown when `e` is false, but might just be "a strange debugger bug" if the statement *appears* to be stepped *without* actually causing the side-effect.

Comment: Try making it with a brackets and `Debug.Print`ing the value of `e` to the Console.

Comment: Does it actually throw the exception if you step over the current line? It's possible your symbols are out of date and need rebuilding.

Comment: I've seen stuff like this happen when my build was messed up.  Try clean/rebuild.

Comment: Does the code match the binary that you are debugging?  Grasping here...

Comment: Did you make a change to the code and run the debug before building it. This could result in the line numbers not matching what you're actually seeing on VS. Does the debugger actually throw the exception or just highlights the line of code as it's stepping through it?

Comment: no, there is not exception throwed. It the first validation (and the only one). I know that this is giving false because all elements of table `fracciones` has a datetime setted on the correct field. If I use brackets `{}` as I said, it works well. But I want to know why without them is not working. And NO, there is no `;` anywhere.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054987 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941321 .  Neither appear to actually be relevant to your problem, though...

Comment: While debugging, changing code causes problem like this sometimes.

Comment: If it's not actually throwing, it sounds like your debugging symbols are messed up.  Try a clean rebuild.

Comment: @Lee yes, it throws it.

Comment: Well, is it actually throwing the exception or not?

Comment: I said yes, If I press F10, it throws the exception

Comment: I bet if you remove the try catch after it or put something between them (like WriteLine();) that won't happen anymore ;)

Comment: The bug only seems to happen when the if results in an exception which is directly followed by a try/catch.  Are you sure it's actually thrown? I was able to replicate everything, but even when the cursor hits the throw, it doesn't actually throw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw a very similar question on SO recently but I cannot find it. While I'm off looking, here is what I remember from it, in case it helps ease your mind:

The symptoms were:

- Stepping through code via the debugger was stopping on a line that should not be executed
- The line of code is *not actually executed* when run outside of a debugger
- Adding curly braces around the offending line of code fixes the problem.

The reason has to do with the extra op codes that are emitted in Debug-enabled releases, to support step-through debugging. The actual IL code emitted for such releases includes extra "no-op" IL commands that do nothing except exist, and are used when stepping through code to break execution just before and/or after the "real" operations have run.

In this case, the IDE is just getting confused about which line of code is the "current" one based on the IL code it's trying to step through. The extra op code is there, as it should be, but the debugger IDE is incorrectly associating it with the previous line of code. The yellow highlight is in the wrong place.

I don't remember the exact conditions that make this happen (the answer to the original question actually dug into the IL to explain it, hopefully someone else can find that question!). Adding the braces causes the compiler to emit no-op op codes specifically to represent the braces, which is why the problem vanishes.

Comment: Your second bullet suggests that the line of code *is* executed when run *inside* the debugger, but that is not the case. The debugger looks like it stopped on the line, but the line is definitely not actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

By chance - is there another variable somewhere defined named 'e' at a different scope, causing the compiler to get confused as to which value to use? Try changing 'e' to some other name.

Comment: yup, I tried with different names. e is not very descriptive :P as you can see, I tried with f, and with no variables using. Same results